# nHibernate Domain Model and Mapping Files in Separate Projects

Tags: .net, nhibernate

Is there a way to separate out the domain objects and mapping files into two separate projects?  I would like to create one project called MyCompany.MyProduct.Core that contains my domain model, and another project that is called MyCompany.MYProduct.Data.Oracle that contains my Oracle data mappings.  However, when I try to unit test this I get the following error message:

> Named query 'GetClients' not found.

Here is my mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="MyCompany.MyProduct.Core"
                   namespace="MyCompany.MyProduct.Core"                   
                   >
  <class name="MyCompany.MyProduct.Core.Client" table="MY_CLIENT" lazy="false">
    <id name="ClientId" column="ClientId"></id>
    <property name="ClientName" column="ClientName" />
    <loader query-ref="GetClients"/>
  </class>
  <sql-query name="GetClients" callable="true">
    <return class="Client" />
    call procedure MyPackage.GetClients(:int_SummitGroupId)
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is my unit test:

```
        try
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.Configure();
            cfg.AddAssembly( typeof( Client ).Assembly );

            ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            IStatelessSession session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession();

            IQuery query = session.GetNamedQuery( "GetClients" );
            query.SetParameter( "int_SummitGroupId", 3173 );
            IList<Client> clients = query.List<Client>();

            Assert.AreNotEqual( 0, clients.Count );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

I think I may be improperly referencing the assembly, because if I do put the domain model object in the MyComapny.MyProduct.Data.Oracle class it works.  Only when I separate out in to two projects do I run into this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, It's possible. If the mappings are on the assembly "MyCompany.MYProduct.Data.Oracle" then you have to pass THAT assembly to cfg.AddAssembly(). You're are using the assembly "MyCompany.MyProduct.Core"

`cfg.AddAssembly("MyCompany.MYProduct.Data.Oracle");`

Comment: Thank you!  That was just the answer I was needing.