# Nhibernate Models in external Project: NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: Class is not mapped

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem with my new project structure.
I excluded the Models folder in another Project and added the references to the existing Nhibernate Project. This is my setup:

KUNDEN.cs:

```
namespace webportale_ger_webservice.Model
{
public class KUNDEN
{
    public KUNDEN() { }
    public virtual int AR { get; set; }
    public virtual STRASSE STRASSE { get; set; }
    public virtual BLZ BLZ { get; set; }
    public virtual KST KST { get; set; }
    public virtual KTRAEGER KTRAEGER { get; set; }
    public virtual double? KNUMMER { get; set; }
}}
```

KUNDEN.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping namespace="webportale_ger_webservice.Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">  <class name="KUNDEN" table="KUNDEN" lazy="false" >
<id name="AR" column="AR"><generator class="webportale_ger_webservice.Routinen.NextKey,webportale ger webservice" /></id>
<many-to-one name="STRASSE">
  <column name="ARSTRASSE" not-null="false" />
</many-to-one>    
<many-to-one name="BLZ">
  <column name="ARBLZ"  not-null="false" />
</many-to-one>      
<many-to-one name="KST">
  <column name="ARKSTREF"  not-null="false" />
</many-to-one>
<many-to-one name="KTRAEGER">
  <column name="arktraeger_k"  not-null="false" />
</many-to-one>

<property name="KNUMMER">
  <column name="KNUMMER" sql-type="numeric" not-null="false" />
</property>  </class></hibernate-mapping>
```

It is possible to compile, but as soon as i want to do something with nhibernate (select KUNDE) i get the following error:

```
 NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QuerySyntaxException: KUNDEN is not mapped [from KUNDEN where ar=54780]
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SessionFactoryHelperExtensions.RequireClassPersister(String name)
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.Tree.FromElementFactory.AddFromElement()
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.fromElement()
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.fromElementList()
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.fromClause()
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.unionedQuery()
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.query()
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.selectStatement()
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlWalker.statement()
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlSqlTranslator.Translate()
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.QueryTranslatorImpl.DoCompile(IDictionary2 replacements, Boolean shallow, String collectionRole)
   bei NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory.CreateQueryTranslators(IASTNode ast, String queryIdentifier, String collectionRole, Boolean shallow, IDictionary`2 filters, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
   bei NHibernate.Engine.Query.QueryPlanCache.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow, IDictionary2 enabledFilters)
   bei NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.GetHQLQueryPlan(IQueryExpression queryExpression, Boolean shallow)
   bei NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CreateQuery(String queryString)
   bei webportale_ger_webservice.web_api.Stamm_SELECT_Kunde() in C:\Quellen\VSWebNeoBackEnd\VSWebNeoBackEnd\VSWebNeoBackEnd\project india webservice\webportale_ger_webservice.asmx.cs:Zeile 664.
```

All mapping files are marked as embedded ressource.
I assume it has something to do with the namespace or assembly. 
my configuration:

```
     static NHibernateHelper()
    {
        configuration.Configure();
        configuration.AddAssembly("VSWebNeoBackEndModel");


        sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

web.config:

```
     <hibernate-configuration> 
<session-factory>...
               <mapping assembly="VSWebNeoBackEndModel" />
    ...     </session-factory>   
</hibernate-configuration>
```

The assemblyname of the models-project is: `VSWebNeoBackEndModel` 
The namespace of the models-project is: `webportale_ger_webservice`

The assemblyname of the mapping/nhibernate project is: `webportale ger webservice`
The namespace of the  mapping/nhibernate project is: `webportale_ger_webservice`

everything worked fine before excluding the models in another project. what did i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution in this post:

[nHibernate Domain Model and Mapping Files in Separate Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622229/nhibernate-domain-model-and-mapping-files-in-separate-projects)

i struggled with assembly names.